# How to add an “INCLUDE” part in an Index Created as a part of CONSTRAINT

Tags: sql-server, index, t-sql, optimization

I am going through the execution plan of a `tsql` query.

[image]

There is a `key LookUp (Clustered)` in the plan. To avoid this `Key LookUp`, I tried to **Include** a column (`Status_Ind`) to The Index (The Index used in execution plan). But I realize that optimizer is using two Indexes, One the Primary Key index and the 2nd one, an index automatically created as a part of a Constraint (`A UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED Index`). I find no way to add an include part in this Index.

How do we add an **INCLUDE** in an index which is automatically created (through CONSTRAINTS)? I am really a beginner in Query optimization.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to have an `INCLUDE` column for an index that enforces a constraint.  [This has been brought up](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/181646/add-ability-to-add-non-unique-included-columns-to-unique-constraints), but marked as "won't fix".

If the benefits of having a covering index are that great, consider revising the indexing strategy that you currently have on that table to maximize query performance.

Answer (score 1):

> How do we add an INCLUDE in an index which is automatically created (through CONSTRAINTS)?

Answer: INCLUDE (column [ ,... n ] ) represents non key column, Column names cannot be repeated in the INCLUDE list and cannot be used simultaneously as both key and non-key columns.

Check [Create Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) Arguments--> Include and [Create Indexes with Included Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx)

I would advice to check different option and plan for indexes that you are looking for

Comment: I think the OP is asking more about how to get `INCLUDE` columns when defining a constraint.

Comment: @ThomasStringer, You would be right, but OP need to confirm that we get it right or it mean something else?